# How to call mbstowcs properly?

Tags: android, linux, java-native-interface

size_t mbstowcs(wchar_t *dest, const char *src, size_t n);

I have some information encoded using gb2312 which needs to change to unicode in android platform.

1.before calling this method, is it right to setlocale(LC_ALL, "zh_CN.UTF-8")?

2.how large need to allocate to dest?

3.What to pass to n, is it strlen(src)?

Thank you very much.

Answer (score 2):

`mbstowcs()` will convert a string from the current locale's multibyte encoding into a wide character string.  Wide character strings are not necessarily unicode, but on Linux they are (UCS32).

If you set the locale to `zh_CN.UTF-8` then the current locale's multibyte encoding will be UTF-8, not GB2312.  You would need to set a GB2312 locale for the input to be treated using that multibyte encoding.

The C standard implies that a single multibyte character will produce at most one wide character, so you can use `strlen(src)` as the upper bound on the number of wide characters required:

```
size_t n = strlen(src) + 1;
wchar_t *dest = malloc(n * sizeof dest[0]);
```

(glibc has an extension to the standard `mbstowcs()` interface, which allows you to pass it a `NULL` pointer to find out exactly how many wide characters will be produced by the conversion, but that won't help you on Android.)  It works like this:

```
size_t n = mbstowcs(NULL, src, 0) + 1;
```

The value of `n` that should be passed is the maximum number of wide characters that should be written through the `dest` pointer, including the terminating null wide character.

However, you should instead look into using `libiconv`, which has been successfully compiled for Android.  It allows you to explicitly choose the source and destination character sets you are interested in, and is a much better fit for this problem.

Comment: n is always 1 when I test. what's the meaning in your first line?

Comment: @Aaron: Sorry, that was actually a glibc extension to `mbstowcs()`, not available on Android - I have updated the answer.